# Adding a negative int to a byte value?

Tags: c#

I know this is a pretty simpleton question, and I have tried google first, but I'm currently stumped here. I'm clearly missing something obvious.

How do you subtract a negative integer from a byte value?

```
//Code simplified greatly for simple simplicity :)
byte BaseValue = 10;
int Modifer = -2;

BaseValue += Modifer; //Should end up with BaseValue = 8
```

I've tried declaring Modifer has a byte (can't have negatives), I've tried declaring it as a sbyte (can't cast sbyte to byte).

In this case 8 is still a valid value for a byte type so not sure why I can't subtract from it.

How do you actually do what I'm trying to do? Again, this strikes me as a dirt simple mistake but I can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried using casting and `-` operation?

Comment: If this is a duplicate, point me to the duplicate. Don't just mark it as duplicate without any other information.

Comment: Samvel Petrosov  I'm not sure I understand what you mean. thanks

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjL28W

Comment: Great... yes thanks. that works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: please read the question and answers mentioned by @JonSkeet, there are a lot of things to think before trying to do arithmetical operations with bytes.

Comment: *Every* time a question is closed as a duplicate, there's *always* a link to the duplicate at the top. It's impossible (as far as I'm aware) to close it as a duplicate without the duplicate itself being linked.